# Pre-requisite knowledge before diving into algorithms

Tags: algorithms, education, mathematical-foundations

I'm having some difficulty trying to follow what the authors of some of the more highly recommended books on algorithms. I ran into the same problem when trying out some online courses. My goal is to prepare myself to start learning fundamental algorithms for use in low-level languages by means of understanding them mathematically. So far, a guide on wiki is a good resource to decipher the symbols, but I'm not sure that will suffice.

Is there anything besides [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) that a person would need before learning algorithms besides basic algebra concepts?

Comment: I suggest a course in discrete mathematics.

Comment: Thanks, @YuvalFilmus -- I actually took one ages ago. Couldn't remember much though. Time to dust off some memories...

Comment: I recommend Book of Proof (pre-load) into Concrete Mathematics (as required).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To learn algorithms mathematically you will need to have a basic understanding of

- Proofs(basically using induction)
- summations and
- asymptotic notations(like Big-O , Big-Omega)

To learn the above subjects I recommend this course from  https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-spring-2015/